# unble to group by date in my query

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, datetime, join

I am firing following query>>

```
SELECT sauda_date, 
   Sum(CASE 
         WHEN buy_sell = 1 
              AND scrip_code = 'ADANIENT' 
              AND sauda_date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '1 Mar 2013') AND 
                                     CONVERT(DATETIME, '1 Apr 2013') THEN 
         trade_qty 
         ELSE 0 
       END)            AS BuyQty, 
   Sum(CASE 
         WHEN buy_sell = 2 
              AND scrip_code = 'ADANIENT' 
              AND sauda_date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '1 Mar 2013') AND 
                                     CONVERT(DATETIME, '1 Apr 2013') THEN 
         trade_qty 
         ELSE 0 
       END)            AS SellQty, 
   Sum(CASE 
         WHEN buy_sell = 1 
              AND scrip_code = 'ADANIENT' THEN trade_qty 
         ELSE 0 
       END) - Sum(CASE 
                    WHEN buy_sell = 2 
                         AND scrip_code = 'ADANIENT' THEN trade_qty 
                    ELSE 0 
                  END) AS CarryForword 
FROM   tradefile 
WHERE  scrip_code = 'ADANIENT' 
GROUP  BY sauda_date
```

and i am getting following result :

```
    sauda_date | Buy_Qty | SellQty | CarryForward

   01 Mar 2013     2000      0         2000
   01 Mar 2013        0     2000          0
   01 Mar 2013     4000      0         4000
   02 Mar 2013        0     1000       3000
   02 Mar 2013     2000       0        5000
   03 Mar 2013        0     4000       1000
```

**But I wanted it as:**

```
    sauda_date | Buy_Qty | SellQty | CarryForward

   01 Mar 2013     6000     2000       4000
   02 Mar 2013     2000     1000       5000
   03 Mar 2013        0     4000       1000
```

**As we can see from tables:**

```
CaryyForward=Buy_Qty-Sell_Qty;

01 Mar 2013 is date and Buy_Qty=sum(buy_Qty) for 01 Mar 2013.
02 Mar 2013 is date and Buy_Qty=sum(buy_Qty) for 02 Mar 2013.
```

[Same for Sell_Qty and CarryForward].

I tried with different group by in case when , but came to know that its not allowed in case when.

I also tried by using different where conditions but not worked.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the query in a subquery, eg

```
SELECT  sauda_date , 
        MAX(Buy_Qty) Buy_Qty,
        MAX(SellQty) SellQty, 
        MAX(CarryForward) CarryForward
FROM
        (
            -- ...put your current query here ...
        ) x
GROUP   BY sauda_date
```

Comment: paste the whole query here. there must be something missing did you remove the `ALIAS` `x`?

Comment: yeah error is there : Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27531/discussion-between-j-w-and-freelancer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the group by clause with more than one parameter. Note the piece I have added to the end of your code:

```
select sauda_date,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 
                         and scrip_code='ADANIENT' 
                         and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'1 Mar 2013') 
                                        and convert(datetime,'1 Apr 2013') 
                    THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS BuyQty,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 
                         and scrip_code='ADANIENT' 
                         and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'1 Mar 2013') 
                                        and convert(datetime,'1 Apr 2013') 
                    THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS SellQty ,
          SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 
                        and scrip_code='ADANIENT' 
                   THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) 
              - SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 
                              and scrip_code='ADANIENT' 
                         THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS CarryForword 
from tradefile 
where scrip_code='ADANIENT' 
group by sauda_date, Buy_Qty,  SellQty, CarryForward
```

Does that not collapse the totals up for you?

Comment: nope, its not allowing me to have multiple columns in group by

Comment: no its not. Still error:Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
Invalid column name 'Buy_Qty'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
Invalid column name 'SellQty'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
Invalid column name 'CarryForward'.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, sauda_date))
```

Without having your sample data I can't be sure, but it looks like you have different TIME parts on each row in the table.
Grouping by datetime will make difference between `2013-04-04 08:24:13.790` and `2013-04-04 17:24:13.790` for example. Above query will convert both to `2013-04-04 00:00:00.000` first.

Edit: you will also have to replace sauda_date in SELECT list with the same construct.

[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa896/1)

Answer (score 0):

My database is also having time attached to it.
So due to different timings it was taking different dates.

So I written query as :

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date) AS sauda_date,SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='ADANIENT' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'1 Mar 2013') and convert(datetime,'1 Apr 2013') THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS BuyQty,SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 and scrip_code='ADANIENT' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'1 Mar 2013') and convert(datetime,'1 Apr 2013') THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS SellQty ,     SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='ADANIENT' THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) -SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 and scrip_code='ADANIENT' THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS CarryForword from tradefile where scrip_code='ADANIENT' group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date)
```

and this worked.